# LinqToSql Join with a table and a view

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have a table described as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[WRSA_ID] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[Administrator] [varchar](5) NOT NULL
```

And a view described as

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ProjectView]
AS
SELECT     Project_ID, Project_Name
FROM         WRSA.dbo.projects
```

The WRSA_ID in Project is actually a foreign key of Project_ID in ProjectView but obviously since the table is referencing a view I can't place a foreign key constraint on the table.
In the UI I have both entities Project and ProjectView but due to the lack of foreign key, there is no physical link between them.

I want to select all Projects where a search string is found either in the WRSA_ID/Project_ID or in the Project_Name or Administrator.  How would I do this is LinqToSql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can include both the table and the view in your .DBML and then manually add a relationship between the two. Even if you can't, this won't prevent you from querying the tables as if they were joined. You just need to add a Linq 'join', to tell Linq how the tables should be joined together. Something like this:

```
from project in Project
join projectView in ProjectView on project.WRSA_ID equals projectView.Project_ID
where...
select...
```